# Swift LocationManager - Completion Handler

Tags: swift, testing, core-location

I'm trying to use a Location Protocol to enable the mocking of CLLocationManager & CLLocationManager Delegate functions. I've implemented a completion handler (via a web explainer) to be able to return a location via a delegate however the competition never returns (the delegate does return the correct value).

When writing this post the code doesn't seem to make sense, however, I'm not sure how to solve it in this kind of structure.

Call:

```
 func test_getCurrentLocation_returnsExpectedLocation() {
        var locationManagerMock = LocationManagerMock()
        
        locationManagerMock.locationToReturn = { return CLLocation(latitude: 10.0, longitude: 10.0)}
        
        let sut = LocationService(locationManager: locationManagerMock)
        
        let expectedLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 10.0, longitude: 10.0)
        let completionExpectation = expectation(description: "completion expectation")
        sut.getCurrentLocation { (location) in
            XCTAssertEqual(location.coordinate.latitude, expectedLocation.coordinate.latitude)
            XCTAssertEqual(location.coordinate.longitude, expectedLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            completionExpectation.fulfill()
        }
        wait(for: [completionExpectation], timeout: 1)
    }
```

Location Manager with completion

```
func getCurrentLocation(completion: @escaping (CLLocation) -> Void) {
        self.locationManager.requestLocation()
        
        self.currentLocationCallback = { (location) in
            completion(location)
        }
    }
```

Delegate write to class var

```
func locationManager(_ manager: LocationManagerInterface, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else { return }
        self.currentLocationCallback?(location)
        print("Content from Delegate")
        print(location)
        self.currentLocationCallback = nil
    }
```

Comment: Does your mock call the delegate method immediately when `requestLocation` is called?  You're setting the callback after calling it so it might already be too late at that point.

Comment: Yes, getCurrentLocation() calls locationManager.requestLocation() which then fires into the delegate